# If $3x + 2y \le 5$ and $x > 1$ then $y < 1$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

> Suppose $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, and $3x + 2y \le 5$. Prove that if $x > 1$ then $y < 1$.

I have tried to prove it in this way:

Our goal is to prove that $y < 1$.

We have $3x + 2y \leq 5$, which I simplified to this $x \leq$ $\frac{5-2y}{3}$

Now we have $1 < x \leq$ $\frac{5-2y}{3}$, so $1 < \frac{5-2y}{3}$, which I simplified to $3 < 5-2y$, which is $-2 < -2y$, which is $1 > y$  (the sign changes because we divide by a negative number $-2$)

Comment: You want to prove that $y<1$, not $x<1$. But yeah it's ok.

Comment: An alternative is to state the contrapositive, which is trivial: given that $x>1$, if $y \geq 1$ then $3x+2y>5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct, but whenever you're proving an implication (an "if then" statement), you should say explicitly "assume (antecedent)", or the like. So you should say "Let $x > 1$".

(In "$p \implies q$", $p$ is called the antecedent and $q$ the consequent).

Good job.